# How to get the value of selectlist in view into controller with or without Json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, selectlist

I can get the value of a dropdownlist this way but i cant get the value of a selectlist item with this code. What i can do to get the value into my controller for my create action.

My Controller Contains :

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Product products, Design designs, Material materials, Color colors, Picture pictures, FormCollection form,EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Files != null)
        {

            long prod = Convert.ToInt64(form["Product"]);
            pictures.product_id = db.Products.Single(x => x.id == prod).id;
```

My View Contains :

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Productlist"], "id", "name"), "Please Select Product", new { onchange = "productlist()", style = "width:190px; padding:4px; margin:4px;" })
```

i can get dropdownlist value but cant get the value of selectlist..

My View Contains : (SelectList)

```
   <select id="Color" style=" width:190px; padding:4px; margin:4px;" onchange="colorlist()">
   <option label="Please Select Color" ></option>
   </select>
```

so if im gonna need to use json how can i use it inside create action and in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the default binding, then you need an argument in your Create action named "Product" of whatever type you are passing (i.e. string).  Then when the form POSTs to the action the binder will set that argument value to the option selected at the time of POST.